# Copy struct to vector

Tags: c++, vector, struct

Say I have a structure of various data types, I want to copy each single byte in a vector. I do this:

```
vector<unsigned char> myVector;                                     // get a vector
unsigned char buf[sizeof myStructure];                              // get an array
memcpy(&buf, &myStructure, sizeof myStructure);                     // copy struct to array
myVector.insert(myVector.begin(), buf, buf + sizeof myStructure);   // copy array to vector
```

Is there a quickest way that allows me to copy the struct `myStruct` to vector `myVector` without passing through the array `buf`?

Comment: Why not just insert `myStructure`? I.e. use `std::vector<TheTypeOfMyStructure>`.

Comment: You can do that, but unless `std::is_trivially_copyable<MyStructure>::value == true`, the utility of the copied data is extremely limited.

Answer (score 9):

You can try the iterator-pair constructor:

```
auto const ptr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&myStructure);

std::vector<unsigned char> myVector( ptr, ptr + sizeof myStructure );
```